# How to increase size of emoji using 'ArrowUp' in Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm trying to continually increase the size of the balloon emoji 10px when a user pushes the up arrow as well as decrease size by 10px with down arrow on keypad.

I've been trying to set:

```
let size = para.style.fontSize;
```

in order to get a variable for the size and then adjust that value by adding +/- 10px in my function. However, I've tried this method and it seems as if you can not set:

```
para.style.fontSize = size +10;
```

Does anybody have any suggestions to get this to work?

Note: I have not included the size variable in the code below as I found it does not work.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Title of the document</title>
  <style>
    p {
      font-size: 50px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <p></p>

  <script>
    let para = document.querySelector('p');


    window.addEventListener("keydown", e => {
    if (e.key == "ArrowUp") {
      para.style.fontSize = '60px';
    } else {
      para.style.fontSize = '40px';
    }
  });



  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your snippet is working for me when I press the up and down arrow in Chrome.

Comment: Yes, it works for only on the first press. How could you continually press the up arrow for the balloon to grow with each arrow up press? @KodosJohnson

Comment: I posted a solution for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the current fontSize property was null so you can't add to a null value. The second issue is that the fontSize property is actually a string with "px". So if you want to increase or decrease the value, you need to parse out the integer value. Then, when you assign it back to para.style.fontSize, you need to append "px" back.

Here is your code with the changes described above.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Title of the document</title>
  <style>
    p {
      font-size: 50px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <p></p>

  <script>
    let para = document.querySelector('p');
    // Set to default size
    para.style.fontSize = '24px';


    window.addEventListener("keydown", e => {
    var sizeAsInteger = parseInt(para.style.fontSize, 10);
    if (e.key == "ArrowUp") {
      sizeAsInteger += 10;
    } else {
      sizeAsInteger -= 10;
      
    }
    para.style.fontSize = sizeAsInteger + 'px';
  });



  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: what does this line mean: parseInt(para.style.fontSize, 10);

Comment: @TylerMorales That parses a string and returns an integer value from the string. The second argument (10) specifies that the number to be parsed has a base of 10 (0-9) (not binary or hexadecimal).

Answer (score 2):

To achieve growing/shrinking behavior over multiple `keydown` events, you'll need to increment/decrement `para.style.fontSize` per event. Once way this could be done is as follows:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Title of the document</title>
  <style>
    p {
      font-size: 50px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <p></p>

  <script>
    let para = document.querySelector('p');

    window.addEventListener("keydown", e => {

      let currentSize = parseInt(para.style.fontSize);

      // If unable to determine current fontSize, default to 50
      if (isNaN(currentSize)) {
        currentSize = 50;
      }

      // Define the rate of change
      let changeAmount = 5;

      if (e.key == "ArrowUp") {
        para.style.fontSize = (currentSize + changeAmount) + 'px';
      } else {
        // Protect againt zero or negative font sizes via Math.max() 
        para.style.fontSize = Math.max(changeAmount, currentSize - changeAmount) + 'px';
      }
    });
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that if you grab the `size` and then do `console.log(size)`, you will get a blank result for the first round (because it's initially not set) and all subsequent rounds you get the size with `px` appended to the end. Thus, `size + 10` with an initial size of `40px` will give you `40px10`. This results in undesired behavior.

To fix this, you need to remove the `px`, convert to a number, then append the `px` again:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Title of the document</title>
  <style>
    p {
      font-size: 50px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <p></p>

  <script>
    let para = document.querySelector('p');

    window.addEventListener("keydown", e => {
    let size = para.style.fontSize.replace('px', '');
    size = size == '' ? '50' : size; // size may not be initialized, so default to our intended starting value!
    size = parseInt(size);
    if (e.key == "ArrowUp") {
      para.style.fontSize = (size + 10) + 'px';
    } else {
      para.style.fontSize = (size - 10) + 'px';
    }
  });



  </script>

</body>

</html>
```